# Reachwater Rock door problems?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I must have encountered a glitch in Skyrim. I have been following the [Forbidden Legend](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Forbidden_Legend) quest so far, got the Emerald Dragon Claw, put in the right combo and turned the claw but the door in [Reachwater Rock](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Reachwater_Rock) won't open. How can I get the door to open?

Comment: Are you sure you got the right combo?  Often it's the simplest things that trip you up.

Comment: Did you check [the puzzle bugs on UESP wiki](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Puzzle_Totems#Bugs)?

Answer (score 0):

If you've tried everything legitimate, you can try to use the console to get through the door:
Open console (press the key under the escape key)
Doubleclick somewhere (just for total security)
Type in "tcl" and press enter and exit the console
"Fly" through the door
Open the console, type in "tcl" and press enter

You can also try "opening" (more like destroying) the door by opening the console, clicking on the door and typing "disable" into the console. I'm not sure if the "disable" command is in Skyrim
Unfortunately, this won't work on a console.